# How to find position of a number within a range while starting from a specific position in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

On an Excel sheet, I have numbers in various columns of a row as shown below:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|  A    |  B    |  C    |  D    |  E    |  F    |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|  0    |  0.23 |  0    |  0    |  0.9  |  0.9  |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want to start from a particular column position and find the position relative to the entire range of the next value `0` in the row.

For example:

- If the start position is 1, the result should be `1`.
- If the start position is 2, result should be `3`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) or [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) function to change the referenced array.

Here is an example:
`=MATCH(B3,INDIRECT("R1C"&B4&":R1C6",FALSE),0)+B4-1`

[image: screenshot]